# Make cell background color different for each object in array

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, background-color

I'd like to change the background color to be different for each row in my tableview. For example, my array is 3,2,1. If the first row is equal to my 'total'(3) I want it red, if the second row is minus 1 from my 'total' (3) I want it blue... As I have the code below I'm only able to change the entire tableview color if the criteria is met.

```
if ([myArray containsObject:total]) {     
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }

    else if ([myArray containsObject:totalMinusOne]) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
```

How can I change background for each cell and make it dependent on the if/else statements?

Comment: Is total actually different for each cell? Have you placed breakpoints to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you need -

Use `UITableView` delegate method for that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            break;

        case 1:
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            break;

        case 2:
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cell's ContentView background color.

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: I tried replacing it, but the cell color acts the same but is vertical along the sides.

Comment: Do you have any other views on top the cell.

Comment: Probably you have labels over your contentview. You need to set other views background to [UIColor clearColor].